# What type of XML element is ns2:detail?

Tags: xml

Here is the response I get when I use curl to query an API. I'm really clueless about what "ns2:detail" is. Is it a tag?  Mainly I need to know what kind of element ns2:details is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:plcm-alert-list xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="urn:com:polycom:api:rest:plcm-alert" xmlns:ns3="urn:com:polycom:api:rest:plcm-alert-list">
<ns2:plcm-alert>
<link href="https://192.168.10.70:8443/api/rest/alerts/57cbb714-ffd6-43f6-8874-d592aab4fe38" rel="self" type="application/vnd.plcm.plcm-alert" title="Self Relationship"/>
    <ns2:alert-identifier>57cbb714-ffd6-43f6-8874-d592aab4fe38</ns2:alert-identifier>
    <ns2:code>2603</ns2:code>
    <ns2:detail>Cluster dma2.exlnt.com: Invalid Skype account URI configured for Skype server Boston FE.</ns2:detail>
    <ns2:entity-tag>b8e29e3604a06a1d3244acf0af1837e5</ns2:entity-tag>
    <ns2:timestamp>2017-11-11T02:28:47.557Z</ns2:timestamp>
  </ns2:plcm-alert>
  <ns2:plcm-alert>
    <link href="https://10.224.1.23:8443/api/rest/alerts/8708ea88-c7c2-4563-93b8-f2ef25e2a61e" rel="self" type="application/vnd.plcm.plcm-alert" title="Self Relationship"/>
    <ns2:alert-identifier>8708ea88-c7c2-4563-93b8-f2ef25e2a61e</ns2:alert-identifier>
    <ns2:code>2603</ns2:code>
    <ns2:detail>Cluster dma1.exelnt.com: Invalid Skype account URI configured for Skype server Boston FE.</ns2:detail>
    <ns2:entity-tag>221aab2fd1cc52df17da13b43dd94975</ns2:entity-tag>
    <ns2:timestamp>2017-11-11T02:28:41.254Z</ns2:timestamp>
  </ns2:plcm-alert>
</ns3:plcm-alert-list>
```